# How do I change the delay between rings?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, htc-evo, ringtone

I have an HTC EVO Shift running Android 2.2 (Froyo). When I receive an incoming call the ringtone plays constantly. Each cycle starts immediately after the previous cycle finishes with no delay at all. This happens regardless of which ringtone I select. Short of editing the audio files, is there any way to set the delay between subsequent ringtone cycles?

Comment: Are you using a really short ringtone?  Maybe use something longer (like a song)?

Comment: @Bryan Denny: That's the obvious workaround, but I'm looking for a solution. I'm using the stock ringtones which are fairly short -- most are a second or less. Every other phone I've ever owned had a delay of a couple seconds between cycles. This one plays a continuous loop with is very annoying. There should be a setting (probably hidden) to control this. If it were a Windows Mobile phone I'd look in the registry, but I don't know where to look under Android.

Comment: My guess is that you'd have to take one of those ringtones and add silence to the end of it.  I don't think there is a way to add delay

Answer (score 3):

Bryan above is correct.  There's no way to add a delay, at least not without a custom ROM.  To introduce a pause between the rings find an MP3 you like and use something like Audacity to append a few seconds of silence after it.  Then use that file as your ring tone.